# How to install 10.4 on a partition on a Macbook Pro that was been upgraded to 10.6.8

Tags: macos

10.4 was the original OS.  I have software that wouldn't run on 10.6.8 which I didn't realize until after I'd upgraded to 10.6.8.  I made a partition but restart/"option" won't recognize it.  How can I run the software that requires 10.4?

When I try to reboot, it's as if I'd never made the partition, even though it's on the desktop as a second hard drive.

[image: (screenshot of Disk Utility showing Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD 2 partitions)]

Why can't I access the partition as an option when I reboot?

Comment: Holding C on boot doesn't give me the option of clicking on the new partition.

Comment: C does not let you select a different partition, it selects the optical (CD/DVD) drive to boot from. You need to have the installer disc for this to work. Do you have the installer disc(s) that came with the Mac?

Comment: I have the installer disc.  I thought restart/option would allow me to access the partition, but so far, no luck.  I've also tried to use the option to access a 32 gig thumb drive with a copy of the the startup disc on it.  It isn't recognized either.

Comment: Restart/Option only lets you select a partition (or disc) *that has an OS on it*. You need to start from the installer disc (which does have an OS as well as the installer files), use that to install onto the new partition, and *then* once that's complete, you'll be able to start up from the new partition.

Comment: A copy of the installer disc is on the partition, and I've tried to restart from there.  No luck.

Comment: Don't copy the installer disc to the partition. Put the installer disc in the Mac's optical drive, and **boot from** the disc itself. It'll start up in the Installer application, which will ask you where (i.e. which volume) you want to install the OS onto. Select the new partition there, and let the installer do its thing. After the Installer finishes doing its thing, *then and only then* will you be able to start from the new partition.

Comment: Based on several articles I've read and a couple of comments here, I realize this is the way it's supposed to work.  Again, the problem is that it doesn't give me the option of selecting the partition.

Answer (score 2):

You’ve made the partition, but it won’t be bootable until you install OS X on it. Boot from the install media CD holding C on boot, choosing the new partition as the destination for the install. Once OS X is installed on the partition, it will appear alongside your existing install in Startup Manager when holding alt/option on boot.

Comment: You may want to consider downloading and installing the [Mac OS X 10.4.11 Combo Update (Intel)](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL172?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) after installing OS X 10.4.X from your DVD.